# MGTwitterEngine login page language

Tags: mgtwitterengine

Im using MGTwitterEngine to connect my app to my twitter app account .

I'm trying to switch the "Twitter Info " login page to French . 
Ive change my device settings , store setting , info.plist settings , but still , the first screen is in English .

Doe's anyone know how should I switch it to French ?

Thank you  .

Dk

Answer (score 0):

If you want to ensure that the Web Intent you're rendering is displayed in a specific language, you can pass a lang parameter to any Intent URL.

so, you just have to add to you url var the string &lang=fr

In PHP that would be:

```
echo '<a href="'.$url.'&lang=fr'.'">Sign In with Twitter</a>';
```

look for localization here:
https://dev.twitter.com/docs/intents